# jQuery Slide Up/Slide Down - How can I stop repeating myself?

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidedown, slideup

Using jQuery, when a user clicks on a "plus" sign I slideDown the content and replace the "plus" sign with a "minus" sign and slideUp the content.

But in a very cumbersome manner!

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="a">
<a href="#" id="toggle" class="show_hide">
    <img src="../plus.png" />
</a>

<div class="block-a" style="display: none">
Some that belongs to the belongs to block A
</div>
</div>

<br /><br />    

<div class="b">
<a href="#" id="toggle" class="show_hide">
    <img src="../plus.png" />
</a>

<div class="block-b" style="display: none">
Some that belongs to the belongs to block B
</div>    
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.a .show_hide').toggle(function(){
       $(".a #toggle").find('img').attr('src', '../minus.png' );
       $(".a .block-a").slideDown();

   },function(){
       $(".a #toggle").find('img').attr('src', '../plus.png' );
       $(".a .block-a").slideUp();
   });

    $('.b .show_hide').toggle(function(){
       $(".b #toggle").find('img').attr('src', '../minus.png' );
       $(".b .block-b").slideDown();

   },function(){
       $(".b #toggle").find('img').attr('src', '../plus.png' );
       $(".b .block-b").slideUp();
   });

});
```

How I can stop repeating myself?  There must be a cleaner way to slideUp and slideDown Content.  Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/William3780/cuEU9/7/)

Thanking in advance!

Cheers, Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions.

One is in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfarsaci/cuEU9/9/)

My solution is to add a reference in the toggle to what it has to show/hide

`<a href="#" class="show_hide" data-content='block-a'>`

And then use that value in the javascript

`$('.' + $(this).attr('data-content')).slideDown();`

Off-topic: you shouldn't use the same ID for 2 elements, it has to be unique. I've got rid of the id in my example

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cuEU9/12/)**,

```
$('.show_hide').toggle(function(){
       $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'http://besttravelagent.com/wp-content/themes/best-travel-agent/images/minus.png' );
       $(this).parent().find('div[class^="block"]').slideDown();

   },function(){
       $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'http://besttravelagent.com/wp-content/themes/best-travel-agent/images/plus.png' );
       $(this).parent().find('div[class^="block"]').slideUp()
});
```

A common/generalized function for both links.